# postgresql use insert on CONFLICT update for flow no

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

can I generate serial number use insert conflict not need SEQUENCE ?

this my table :

```
 CREATE TABLE web.flow_no
(
    apply_kind character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    seq_name character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    seq_no numeric(8,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT flow_no_pk PRIMARY KEY (apply_kind, seq_name)       
)
```

but Sql is not OK:
1:

```
insert into web.flow_no(apply_kind,seq_name)values('ISO_FILE','202003')
ON CONFLICT(apply_kind, seq_name)
DO UPDATE SET seq_no=EXCLUDED.seq_no+1
 RETURNING seq_no
```

is alway get 2

2:

```
insert into web.flow_no(apply_kind,seq_name)values('ISO_FILE','202003')
ON CONFLICT(apply_kind, seq_name)
DO UPDATE SET seq_no=
(select seq_no from  web.flow_no where apply_kind=EXCLUDED.apply_kind and 
 seq_name=EXCLUDED.seq_name)+1
 RETURNING seq_no
```

is not thread safe (ATOM): multiple query returning seq_no will conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increment `seq` for each insert conflict, then you should not use the `EXCLUDED` pseudo-table, which refers the row proposed for insertion. Instead, use the table name:

```
INSERT INTO web.flow_no(apply_kind,seq_name)values('ISO_FILE','202003')
ON CONFLICT(apply_kind, seq_name)
DO UPDATE SET seq_no = flow_no.seq_no + 1
RETURNING seq_no
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f4329306b935dd65919c3a1a8135a00f)**.